# Scalable web-hosting for a youtube-like service (no, not porn)

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

My business partner and I are looking for a European web-hosting service (we are situated in Europe). That service needs to be, needs to have:

- international servers, a server for each continent at the very least.
- a high amount of bandwidth.
- highly scalable, since we are expecting to start off small, but as our user base grows so will everything else (again, no porn or phallic jokes) need to do.
- a moderate to supreme customer service.
- of course a small downtime per annum.
- affordable at first, fair as we grow.

I think that is all. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I probably should add that in the beginning we're going to be using european servers only, global servers are for the future scalability.

Comment: well that was a lot of help... At least provide me a link to "the exact original".

Comment: He did - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements